# Django - redirect after pressing comment delete

Tags: python, django

I have a code that deletes comments to from posts.

```py
def comment_remove(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.delete()

    return redirect('Post-detail', pk=post.pk)
```

It deletes comments, but it throws error that `name 'post' is not defined`
I have a same function above in my `views.py` with the same `post.pk` that works fine...

```py
@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.author = request.user
            #comment.author.photo = object.author.profile.image.url
            comment.save()
            return redirect('Post-detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})
```

**Comment model**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Can someone please explain me, where is the problem?
Is it taking no post.pk but comment.pk?

Comment: Do you have any reference of *Post* in `Comment` model?

Comment: #shafik I added my models.py to answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick `pk` from comment object like this

```
comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
....
return redirect('Post-detail', pk=comment.post_id)
```